# Is there a way to collapse ordered rows by terminal values with postgres window clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, self-join

I have a table foo:

| some_fk | some_field | some_date_field |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1990-01-01 |
| 1 | B | 1990-01-02 |
| 1 | C | 1990-03-01 |
| 1 | X | 1990-04-01 |
| 2 | B | 1990-01-01 |
| 2 | B | 1990-01-05 |
| 2 | Z | 1991-04-11 |
| 2 | C | 1992-01-01 |
| 2 | B | 1992-02-01 |
| 2 | Y | 1992-03-01 |
| 3 | C | 1990-01-01 |

`some_field` has 6 possible values: `[A,B,C,X,Y,Z]`
Where `[A,B,C]` signify opening or continuation events and `[X,Y,Z]` signify closing events. How do I get each span of time between the first opening event and closing event of each span, partitioned by `some_fk`, as shown in the table below:

| some_fk | some_date_field_start | some_date_field_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1990-01-01 | 1990-04-01 |
| 2 | 1990-01-01 | 1991-04-11 |
| 2 | 1992-01-01 | 1992-03-01 |
| 3 | 1990-01-01 | NULL |

**Note that a non-terminated time span ends with NULL*

I do have *a* solution that involves 3 common table expressions, but I'm wondering if there is a (better/more elegant/canonical) way to do this in PostgreSQL without nested queries.

My approach was something like:

```sql
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY some_fk ORDER BY some_date_field) AS "rank"
    some_fk,
    some_field,
    some_date_field
  FROM foo    
), openers AS (
  SELECT * FROM ranked WHERE some_field IN ('A','B','C')
), closers AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG("rank") OVER (PARTITION BY some_fk ORDER BY "rank") AS rank_lag
  FROM ranked WHERE some_field IN ('X','Y','Z')
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  openers.some_fk,
  FIRST_VALUE(openers.some_date_field) OVER (PARTITION BY some_fk ORDER BY "rank")
    AS some_date_field_start,
  closers.some_date_field AS some_date_field_end
FROM openers
JOIN closers
  ON openers.some_fk = closers.some_fk
WHERE openers.some_date_field BETWEEN COALESCE(closers.rank_lag, 0) AND closers.rank
```

... but I feel there must be a better way.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to create a grouping ID by creating a running sum of the closing events.  Then in an outer SQL you can Group By and pick min() and max() dates.

```
Select some_fk,min(some_date) as some_date_field_start, max(some_date) as some_date_field _end
From (
    Select some_fk,some_date,
      Sum(Case When some_field in ('X','Y','Z') Then 1 Else 0 End)
        Over (Partition By some_fk Order By some_date
        Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding)
      as some_grouping
    From foo
)
Group By some_fk,some_grouping
Order By some_fk,some_grouping
```

This seems a little simpler at least to me.

Comment: This is certainly more direct. I would need to handle the non-terminated spans in the first line of your script, but I think this fits the bill. Thanks!

Comment: Just add a Coalesce for the null values...

Comment: Well, no. Spans that don't have have a closing event would have NULL for the `some_date_field_end` value. As I read it, your query would return the most recent event in the last span, regardless of whether or not it's a closing event. So I think it would be a case statement in the outer select clause to remediate that. Still - this is a good approach to my eye. Thanks again!

Comment: You're right, that was careless of me.  How about adding a last_value window function with a boolean `last_value(some_field IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')) Over *etc.*`?  Now you have a boolean that tells you whether to nullify your end date

Answer (score 1):

The basis of the query is to use `LAG` to determine if the previous record was a closure.

```
SELECT *,
LAG(some_field) OVER (PARTITION BY some_fk ORDER BY some_date_field) Previous_some_field
FROM foo
```

This allows you to filter on the correct 4 records from your expected results, with the first 2 columns included; your mistake was to put the `WHERE` clause onto that query directly, when what you want to do is use it as is in a sub-query and write the `WHERE` in the main query.
From that point, you have several possibilities to finish the query.

Here is a version using a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT some_fk, some_date_field AS some_date_field_start,
    (
        SELECT MIN(some_date_field)
        FROM foo
        WHERE some_fk = F.some_fk AND some_date_field > F.some_date_field AND some_field IN ('X','Y','Z')
    ) AS some_date_field_end
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    LAG(some_field) OVER (PARTITION BY some_fk ORDER BY some_date_field) Previous_some_field
    FROM foo
) F
WHERE some_field IN ('A','B','C')
AND COALESCE(previous_some_field,'Z') IN ('X','Y','Z')
```

Here is another version using a `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`:

```
SELECT some_fk, some_date_field AS some_date_field_start, some_date_field_end
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    LAG(some_field) OVER (PARTITION BY some_fk ORDER BY some_date_field) Previous_some_field
    FROM foo
) F1
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT MIN(some_date_field) AS some_date_field_end
    FROM foo
    WHERE some_fk = F1.some_fk AND some_date_field > F1.some_date_field AND some_field IN ('X','Y','Z')
) F2
WHERE some_field IN ('A','B','C')
AND COALESCE(previous_some_field,'Z') IN ('X','Y','Z')
```